# html-webpack-plugin not writing to index.html

Tags: angular, gulp, webpack

I'm trying to use html-webpack-plugin to inject my dependencies into my global html template, but so far every time I build, it comes back blank, like so:

`Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":`

Not sure what's going wrong here, can anyone help? I'm using Gulp with Webpack and Angular2.

```
import HtmlWebpack from 'html-webpack-plugin'

const frontendLoader = {
    preloaders: {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'tslint'
    },
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts'
    }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
    }, {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw'
    }]
}
module.exports = {
    frontendConfig: {
        debug: true,
        entry: {
            initial: ['./src/js/initial/initial.js'],
            vendor: ['./src/js/app/vendor'],
            app: ['./src/js/app/index']
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        output: {
            filename: '[name].bundle.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpack({
                inject: 'head',
                template: './public/views/index.html'
            })
        ],
        module: frontendLoader
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the output html look? (Try running it without dev server in order to see this)

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you are trying to include the content of your index.html to the head of the HTML file generated by the HTMLWebpackPlugin. However, I guess what you actually want is to insert the content into the body part.

Instead of

```
plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpack({
                inject: 'head',
                template: './public/views/index.html'
            })
        ]
```

try

```
plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpack({
                inject: 'body',
                template: './public/views/index.html'
            })
        ]
```